# How to retrieve user name from user table by using data (user_id) from another table having relationship

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have two models

**User.php**

```
public function opportunities()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Opportunity');
}
```

**Opportunity.php**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

I have `user_id` column in opportunities table and inserted user id (from user table using Auth)  every time user posts record.

Now i need a view to return *"this post is posted this user"*.

First I find the post id by

```
$posts =  Opportunity::find($id);
$posted_by = User::find($posts->user_id);
return view('opportunity.detail')->with('post', $posts, 'posted_by', $posted_by);
```

I have rendered user name by `{{$posted_by->name}}`

But I  got undefined constant in the view file `$posted_by` while `$post` is fine. Am I doing it in right way or not? I am passing two array variable to the post and its not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller could look like:

```
return view('opportunity.detail', [
    'post' => Opportunity::find($id);
]);
```

In the view to show user name:

```
Post {{ $post->title }} posted by {{ $post->user->name }}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties

If for some reason you want to use `->with()`, do this:

```
->with(['post' => $posts, 'posted_by' => $posted_by]);
```

Or:

```
->with('post', $posts)->with('posted_by', $posted_by);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but opportunity modal don't have name field . opportunity model only has one user_id column to store user's id. But user name should be retrieved from User.php model based on user_id  .... What i did is first finding post id. the record contains user_id.  
My controller :

$posts =  Opportunity::find($id);

        $posted_by = User::where('name')->find($posts->user_id); 
        
        return view('opportunity.detail')->with('post', $posts, 'posted_by', $posted_by);

I will try it anyway

Comment: @ParajuliSunil just try the code. Also, click the link to learn about relationships and dynamic properties.

Comment: Thanks @Alexy Mezenin it worked great!!!. I didn't know it was simple. Its been a week i started using laravel so i don't know much about relationship. thanks again, I think i am gonna read your mentioned link to build review system too.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this

```
public function getUserName() {
 return User::where('id', $this->user_id)->first()->name;
}
```

in your Opportunity.php model and call it in you view

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
  {{ $post->getUserName() }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: This is not how to use relations, see the other answer. You can just return $this->user->name in your getUserName() method